# Limiting the number of url address characters on the site and blocking it

Tags: security, hacking, csf, attacks

hackers are slowing down my server
They send repeated requests with different IPs
They are constantly sending long url addresses like below:

```
mysite.com/asm-nfm555sd5-nfm.mp3asm-dnfm555sd5-nfm.mp3asdnfm555sd5-nfm.mp3asm-dnfm555sd5-nfm.mp3 ...
```

Can I limit the length of the url  address on the server?
I have direct admin with Apache + NginX and cfs firewall

For example, if the length of the url address is more than 300 characters,Block that request &  Block its IP

Hackers are sending requests with url addresses of 1200 characters long to the site and it slows down the server.

Comment: first match on Google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067334/how-to-set-the-allowed-url-length-for-a-nginx-request-error-code-414-uri-too